# Class ' not found in laravel 5.0.16

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in laravel. And I am using Laravel 5.0.16 in my wamp server. I have been learning laravel by free video tutorial available in laracasts.com. I have been trying to fetch data from database. I have checked that my app is already connected to database.

I do have below structure in app folder:

```
-app
   -Http(folder)
   -Other folders (folder)
   -Article.php (file)
   -User.php (file)
```

In side Http folder:

```
   -Controllers (folder)
   -Middleware (folder)
   -Requests (folder)
   -Kernel.php (file)
   -routes.php (file)
```

In Controllers folder:

```
   -ArticleController.php (file)
```

Below is code in side routes, controllers and model file:

```
/*routes*/

  Route::get('articles','ArticleController@index');

/*Controller file*/
use App\models\Article;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class ArticleController extends Controller {
  public function index()
  {
    $users = Article::all();
    return $users;
   }
}

/*Model file - Article.php*/
namespace App\models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Article extends Model {
 protected $table = 'users';
 protected $fillable = ['id','firstname', 'lastname',   'email','reg_date'];
}
```

Where users is DB table with fields.

I am getting below arror:

```
FatalErrorException in ArticleController.php line:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Article' not found
```

I have check other SO forums but they didn't help me, can anyone suggest me what am I missing?

Comment: try moving `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` to the top of the file, above `use App\models\Article;`

Comment: @jfadich: not working :(

Comment: What did the file look like after that change? It's definitely wrong as is. The namespace declaration should come before any use statements. That is the only thing I see that would cause that error.

Comment: it is returning same error like earlier 'class Article not found'.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What does the controller file look like after that change?

Comment: sorry, i didn't get your point..i just move namespace and place before use in controller file.rest file code remain same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here. One the namespace declaration should happen before any use statements.

Second your models uses the `model` namespace but your models aren't in a model directory. The namespace should match the directory structure. So you either need to change the namespace to `use App\Article` (also change the namespace in the model file) or move the model files into a models directory.

So to fix this without moving files update the code to look like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Article;
use App\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class ArticleController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $users = Article::all();
        return $users;
    }
}

/*Model file - Article.php*/
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Article extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['id','firstname', 'lastname',   'email','reg_date'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the top of a controller:

```
use App\models\Article;
```

Or use the full namespace when working with this model:

```
\App\models\Article::all();
```

Comment: use App\models\Article, i have already mentioned in my controller file. and another approach doesn' t work as it also throw error message.

Comment: @AshPatel The second approach might not be working because you need to start with a slash to qualify the name out of the global namespace. So it should be `\App\model\Article::all();`

Comment: After applied secound approach it returning error like: Class 'App\model\Article' not found...there is something wrong i am adding model file in wrong way.

Comment: @AshPatel it should be `models`, not `model`. And since you manually defined namespace, you should put `Article.php` into the `app\models` directory to make it work.